# Is there anything else used instead of slicing the String?

Tags: python-3.x

This is one of the practice problems from Problem solving section of Hackerrank. The problem statement says

> Steve has a string of lowercase characters in range ascii[‘a’..’z’]. He wants to reduce the string to its shortest length by doing a series of operations. In each operation he selects a pair of adjacent lowercase letters that match, and he deletes them.

For example : 'aaabbccc' -> 'ac' , 'abba' -> ''

I have tried solving this using slicing of strings but this gives me timeout runtime error on larger strings. Is there anything else to be used?

My code:

```
s = list(input())

i=1
while i<len(s):
    if s[i]==s[i-1]:
        s = s[:i-1]+s[i+1:]
        i = i-2
    i+=1
if len(s)==0:
    print("Empty String")
else:
    print(''.join(s))
```

This gives me terminated due to timeout message.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Interning each new immutable string can be expensive,
as it has O(N) linear cost with the length of the string.
Consider processing `"aa" * int(1e6)`.
You will write on the order of `1e12` characters to memory
by the time you're finished.

Take a moment (well, take linear time) to
copy each character over to a mutable `list` element:

```
[c for c in giant_string]
```

Then you can perform dup processing by writing a [**tombstone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(data_store))
of `""` to each character you wish to delete,
using just constant time.
Finally, in linear time you can scan through the survivors using `"".join( ... )`

Answer (score 0):

One other possible solution is to use regex. The pattern `([a-z])\1` matches a duplicate lowercase letter. The implementation would involve something like this:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'([a-z])\1')
while pattern.search(s):  # While match is found
    s = pattern.sub('', s)  # Remove all matches from "s"
```

I'm not an expert at efficiency, but this seems to write fewer strings to memory than your solution. For the case of `"aa" * int(1e6)` that [J_H mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56924874/4518341), it will only write one, thanks to `pattern.sub` replacing all occurances at once.